# Staggered grid layout items "NOT" staggering (if thats a word), items are getting laid uniformly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview

I want the items in the `RecyclerView` to be displayed in a staggered form, but it keeps laying out items as if I was using a `GridLayout`. Here is my XML for a post item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/get_upload_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/action_settings"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

            android:src="@drawable/marvel"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/get_upload_image"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:id="@+id/get_upload_title"
                android:text="@string/hello_world"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                android:id="@+id/get_upload_price"
                android:text="@string/hello_world"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:id="@+id/fav_unselected"
            android:src="@drawable/favicon_unchecked"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Here is an image of the RecyclerView:

[image]

What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: Your views seemingly have the same height values. Try changing one to a bit taller or shorter version and you'll see that it's indeed staggered.

Comment: i am downloading the image in each child item from firebase and each image is the same size; does this mean the child items will not stagger

Comment: I mean, what do you expect to happen? If the items in the `RecyclerView` have the same dimensions, it will look like a grid obviously.

Comment: but i need the items to stagger, can u suggest anyway to get that kind of layout

Comment: I don't know what the texts are for under the image, but if you let those have multiple lines, it will get that staggered look eventually. Other solution would be to insert an empty view as a 2nd item and give it some dimension. However, I don't know why you'd force this behavior.

Comment: the idea is; each image is an item a user upload and below it, the title of the item and the numbers represent the price..these are just random texts for now, i really like the staggered layout ...thanks for your time, i would try inserting an empty view

Comment: Since the title can be multiple lines long, I guess you should just let it be like this. If a user sets a longer title, it will get staggered. Also, you can play with the image sizes by not using a fixed width AND height together, but letting it be either max this wide OR max that high. This way the images would have different height values meaning it would get staggered more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Change the Size of Images or User Long and Short Text

Comment: Could you post some examples to clarify your answer?